# Hiding last column in QTreeView

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qtreeview

I have treeview with 9 columns. I want to hide columns from 4 to 9.
The code bellow hide columns 4,5,6,7,8 , but not 9.  What is wrong with the code?

```
header = self.ui.visitors_treeview.header()
    for column in range(3, self.model.column_count()):
        header.hideSection(header.logicalIndex(header.visualIndex(column)))
```

But if i will try to hide column from view.. it also still visible:

```
        self.ui.visitors_treeview.hideColumn(8)
```

Comment: Does `header.hideSection(8)` work? Do you really need the back and forth between logical and visual indexes (I guess not, but I could be wrong).

Comment: No, hideSection(8) does not hide 8 column. I guess i cant fully understand relation between visual and logical indexes.

Comment: As stated in the doc, "the visual index will change if a section is moved, but the logical index will not change", meaning that if you move col #1 before col #0, the new col #0 has a logical index of 1 and a visual index of 0. But that's another story. I'm running out of ideas of why you can't hide that column. Is there anything special in it?